# Why is my terminal[stdin/out] fully buffered instead of line buffered?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

According to the APUE:

```
ISO C requires the following buffering characteristics:
  • Standard input and standard output are fully buffered, if and only if they do not
refer to an interactive device.
  • Standard error is never fully buffered.
This, however, doesn’t tell us whether standard input and standard output are
unbuffered or line buffered if they refer to an interactive device and whether standard
error should be unbuffered or line buffered. Most implementations default to the
following types of buffering:
  • Standard error is always unbuffered.
  • All other streams are line-buffered if they refer to a terminal device; otherwise,
they are fully buffered.
```

For my example(OS:ubuntu20.64, Compiler:gcc ):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"apue.h"

void pr_stdio(const char*, FILE *);
int is_unbuffered(FILE*);
int is_linebuffered(FILE*);
int buffer_size(FILE*);

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    char buf[1024];
    fputs("enter any char\n", stdout);
    
    if(getchar() == EOF)
        err_sys("getchar error");
    fputs("one line to standard error\n", stderr);

    pr_stdio("stdin", stdin);

    //set stdout -> IOLBF
    if(setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOLBF, 555) == 0)
        printf("setvbuf success\n");

    pr_stdio("stdin", stdin);
    pr_stdio("stdout", stdout);
    pr_stdio("stderr", stderr);

    if((fp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r")) == NULL)
        err_sys("fopen error");
    if(getc(fp) == EOF)
        err_sys("gets error");
    pr_stdio("/etc/passwd", fp);
    exit(0);

}
void pr_stdio(const char* name, FILE* fp)
{
    printf("stream = %s, ", name);
    if(is_unbuffered(fp))
        printf("unbuffered");
    else if(is_linebuffered(fp))
        printf("line buffered");
    else 
        printf("fully buffered");
    
    printf(", buffer size = %d\n", buffer_size(fp));
}

int is_unbuffered(FILE* fp)
{
    return (fp->_flags & _IONBF);
}

int is_linebuffered(FILE* fp)
{
    return (fp->_flags & _IOLBF);u
}

int buffer_size(FILE* fp)
{
    return (fp->_IO_buf_end - fp->_IO_buf_base);
}
```

Some other information which can help solve this problem:

```
<stdio.h>:
/* The possibilities for the third argument to `setvbuf'.  */
#define _IOFBF 0        /* Fully buffered.  */
#define _IOLBF 1        /* Line buffered.  */
#define _IONBF 2        /* No buffering.  */

<struct_FILE.h>:
struct _IO_FILE
{
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  char *_IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char *_IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char *_IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char *_IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char *_IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char *_IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char *_IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char *_IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */

  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

I run it:

```
enter any char
l
one line to standard error
stream = stdin, fully buffered, buffer size = 1024
setvbuf success
stream = stdin, fully buffered, buffer size = 1024
stream = stdout, fully buffered, buffer size = 1024
stream = stderr, unbuffered, buffer size = 1
stream = /etc/passwd, fully buffered, buffer size = 4096
```

The strange thing is that it was full buffering before I set it:

```c
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOLBF, 555)
```

It returns 0, which means success, and it is still like this after setting it.

**One more thing to add.
There is also a strange phenomenon:**
If I call the setvbuf() in this way :

```
char mybuf[1024];
//I use the buf in user space, instead of the space which OS offers. 
setvbuf(stdin, mybuf, _IOLBF, 555)
```

The result as follows:

```
//***
stream = stdin, fully buffered, buffer size = 1024
setvbuf success
stream = stdin, line buffered, buffer size = 555
//***
```

Oh,it succeed when I used user space!
But why is the first scenario a failure?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I noticed this tidbit in the man page: "The setvbuf() function may be used only after opening a stream and before any other operations have been performed on it."

Comment: @Jason,I understand what you mean. And I add some other infomation above,which may reverse your conclusion.If you are right, the second setvbuf() may not work.

Comment: `return (fp->_flags & _IOLBF);` that is odd. Your code is missing `#include`s. _Why_ do you assume that `_IOLBF` would be set in `fp->_flags`?

Comment: Wasn't this asked in the last day or two?

Comment: The tag [tag:std] is for C++ standard library, don't use it with C questions.

Comment: @KamilCuk，I was wrong.Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of the book.Standard C did not provide a method to test if a FILE stream is fully buffered, no buffered or line buffered.The way to test it is to read the source code.Thank you for the inspiration.

Comment: @dbush, I am a newbie in stackoverflow. I found some relevant Q&A, but I thought they did't solve my problem.Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

> ISO C requires

You are *not* working with ISO C. ISO C is abstract. Your code is using specific details of that single one specific implementation. It is not abstract. You are tightly tied to the specific single one implementation you are using. Buttom line, you are using GNU glibc.

> ```
> return (fp->_flags & _IONBF);
> ```

This is not how to check buffering of a `FILE` stream in glibc. Glibc does some functions https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html .

*In glibc* (in this particular single one specific implementation, not in any other) there is a field `_flags` in `FILE` structure and there are flags defined in `libio.h` https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/libio.h#L74 . Note that the file libio.h is *not* installed on the system. Additionally, there are extensions from glibc https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html .

```
int is_unbuffered(FILE* fp) {
#define _IO_UNBUFFERED        0x0002  /* copied */
    return fp->_flags & _IO_UNBUFFERED;
}

int is_linebuffered(FILE* fp) {
    return __flbf(fp);
}

int buffer_size(FILE* fp) {
    return __fbufsize(fp);
}
```

Also, you might be interested in the setvbuf dispatch function for FILE operations on normal files defined here https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/libio/iosetvbuf.c.html#33 .

Comment: Maybe I should edit my code in this way: 
`
#define _IO_LINE_BUF          0x0200         /* copied */
#define _IO_UNBUFFERED        0x0002   /* copied */

int is_unbuffered(FILE* fp)
{ 
    return (fp->_flags & 0x00000002);
}

int is_linebuffered(FILE* fp)
{ 
    return (fp->_flags& 0x00000200);
}
`
And  I ran it, It worked as expected.
Thanks